# New Processes don't start in Docker running FastApi

Tags: python, docker, fastapi, python-multiprocessing, uvicorn

I'm running FastApi inside a docker container with 8 cpus available, and I want to utilise them via python multiprocessing.

Running my program outside the docker container, everything works pretty much (see below) as I expect, but when I build and run the container, the child processes don't start.

Here's the relevant code from my application

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager, Queue
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from fastapi import FastAPI

CLIENT_CORES = 5
connection = "mongo_connection_string"

@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()

    global dbWorkers
    global clientWorkers

    global clientQueue
    global clientResponse

    

    #resources
    dbQueue = Queue()
    clientQueue = Queue()
    clientResponse = manager.dict()
    psetObjects = manager.dict()
    dbWorkers = []
    clientWorkers = []

    #start client and db workers
    config_processes(dbQueue,clientQueue,clientResponse,psetObjects)

    yield
    
    graceful_shutdown()

def config_processes(dbQueue,clientQueue,clientResponse,psetObjects):

    #db
    start_db_workers(dbQueue,psetObjects)

    #client
    start_client_workers(clientQueue,psetObjects,dbQueue,clientResponse)


def start_db_workers(dbQueue,psetObjects):
    print("Building db Workers")

    for p in range(DB_PROCS):
        dbworker = Process(target=db_worker,args=(connection,dbQueue,psetObjects,p))
        dbWorkers.append(dbworker)
        dbworker.start()

    print("db Pool of {} db Worker(s) Built -OK".format(DB_PROCS))


def start_client_workers(clientQueue,psetObjects,dbQueue,clientResponse):
    print("Building client Workers")
    print("CLIENT CORES: {}".format(CLIENT_CORES))
    
    for p in range(CLIENT_CORES):
        clientWorker = Process(target=client_worker,args=(clientQueue,psetObjects,dbQueue,clientResponse,p),name="client-worker-{}".format(p))
        clientWorkers.append(clientWorker)
        clientWorker.start()
    
    print("Client Pool of {} Worker(s) Built -OK".format(len(clientWorkers)))

    
def db_worker(connection,dbQueue,pset_objects,n):
    dbworker = DbWorker(connection,dbQueue,pset_objects,n)
    print("built dbworker {}".format(n))
    dbworker.listen()

def client_worker(clientQueue,psetObjects,dbQueue,clientResponse,p):
    clientworker = ClientWorker(clientQueue,psetObjects,dbQueue,clientResponse,p)
    print("built client worker {}".format(p))
    clientworker.listen()
```

Running in docker, the log shows:

```
INFO:     Started server process [7]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
CPUS: 8
Building db Workers
db Pool of 1 db Worker(s) Built -OK
Building client Workers
CLIENT CORES: 5
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:80 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

i.e. we never see the `client_worker()` and `db_worker()` targets are never called, and `start_client_workers()` never completes. Running direct with uvicorn I get:

```
CPUS: 8
INFO:     Started server process [40230]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
Building db Workers
db Pool of 1 db Worker(s) Built -OK
Building client Workers
CLIENT CORES: 5
Client Pool of 5 Worker(s) Built -OK
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
built client worker 4
built client worker 2
built client worker 1
built client worker 0
built client worker 3
built dbworker 0
```

I notice the absurd number of server processes in the latter example, and I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong in trying to use multiprocessing with FastApi in the first place - though I understand, for example, from [here](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/discussions/7442) that this is (or should be) ok, and in any case, my issue is with the difference between the behaviour in docker vs outside it.

Is there a way to get the containerised behaviour I'm looking for using this method or should I be looking to refactor to use Gunicorn, docker swarm or similar? If the latter, please can you point me to how to do this properly? Thanks.

------- EDIT 12/02/2024 in light of answer from @datawookie

I've implemented (exactly) the answer given below in a fresh environment and, very strangely, see the following:

```
INFO:     Started server process [1]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
Building db Workers
db Pool of 2 db Worker(s) Built -OK
Building client Workers
CLIENT CORES: 5
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
built client worker 0
built dbworker 1
built client worker 1
built dbworker 0
built client worker 3
built client worker 4
built client worker 2
```

Notably, although I see all the print statements from `client_worker()`, I don't see the final call to `print(f"Client Pool of {len(clientWorkers)} Worker(s) Built -OK")` which was evident in `@datawookie`'s answer. This echoes the behaviour I've been seeing in my own application environment - namely that the last Process.start() call doesn't seem to complete - which, even more bizarrely, occurrs no matter the value I choose for `CLIENT_CORES` - it's always the case that the last call to `Process.start()` does not return.

Things get even weirder when I add the full logic from my application (building a `ClientWorker` object and calling the `.listen()` method as shown in the initial question. In this case, the output is:

```
INFO:     Started server process [7]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
CPUS: 8
Building db Workers
db Pool of 1 db Worker(s) Built -OK
Building client Workers
CLIENT CORES: 5
built dbworker 0
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:80 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

But if I just comment out the `.listen()` call, like this:

```
def client_worker(clientQueue,psetObjects,dbQueue,clientResponse,p):
    clientworker = ClientWorker(clientQueue,psetObjects,dbQueue,clientResponse,p)
    print("built client worker {}".format(p))
    # clientworker.listen()
```

I get this:

```
INFO:     Started server process [6]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
CPUS: 8
Building db Workers
db Pool of 1 db Worker(s) Built -OK
Building client Workers
CLIENT CORES: 5
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:80 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
built client worker 0
built dbworker 0
built client worker 2
built client worker 1
built client worker 3
built client worker 4
```

For clarity, `ClientWorker.listen()` is of the form:

```
def listen(self):
    print("started")
    while self.stay_alive == True:
        try:
            args = self.clientQueue.get(block=True)
            #do_work(args)
        except:
           #report_error()
```

again, everything works pretty much fine in uvicorn alone, please can someone explain what's going on in the docker environment?!

Comment: You need to remove the trailing comma from `from multiprocessing import Process, manager, Queue,`.

Comment: Also I think that you probably mean `Manager` rather than `manager` in that import statement as well?

Comment: I think you also need to `from contextlib import asynccontextmanager`. Sorry to be nit-picky about these things, but ideally a minimal reproducible example should run without errors.

Comment: Noted, thanks. Edited to reflect these problems - the app is substantially larger so I had to crop out the relevant portions - didn't do a great job of that at 2am this morning!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is with print buffering. Here's a working version of the code.

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.11.4-slim

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY main.py .

CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app"]
```

The key addition is `ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` which forces immediate printing.

`requirements.txt`

```
fastapi==0.109.2
uvicorn==0.27.1
```

`main.py`

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Manager
from fastapi import FastAPI

CLIENT_CORES = 5
DB_PROCS = 2
connection = "mongo_connection_string"

app = FastAPI()

def start_lifespan_resources():
    manager = Manager()

    global dbWorkers
    global clientWorkers
    global clientQueue
    global clientResponse

    dbQueue = Queue()
    clientQueue = Queue()
    clientResponse = manager.dict()
    psetObjects = manager.dict()
    dbWorkers = []
    clientWorkers = []

    config_processes(dbQueue, clientQueue, clientResponse, psetObjects)

def stop_lifespan_resources():
    for worker in dbWorkers + clientWorkers:
        worker.terminate()
        worker.join()

    print("All workers terminated.")

def config_processes(dbQueue, clientQueue, clientResponse, psetObjects):
    start_db_workers(dbQueue, psetObjects)
    start_client_workers(clientQueue, psetObjects, dbQueue, clientResponse)

def start_db_workers(dbQueue, psetObjects):
    print("Building db Workers")
    for p in range(DB_PROCS):
        dbworker = Process(target=db_worker, args=(connection, dbQueue, psetObjects, p))
        dbWorkers.append(dbworker)
        dbworker.start()
    print(f"db Pool of {DB_PROCS} db Worker(s) Built -OK")

def start_client_workers(clientQueue, psetObjects, dbQueue, clientResponse):
    print("Building client Workers")
    print(f"CLIENT CORES: {CLIENT_CORES}")
    for p in range(CLIENT_CORES):
        clientWorker = Process(target=client_worker, args=(clientQueue, psetObjects, dbQueue, clientResponse, p), name=f"client-worker-{p}")
        clientWorkers.append(clientWorker)
        clientWorker.start()
    print(f"Client Pool of {len(clientWorkers)} Worker(s) Built -OK")

def db_worker(connection, dbQueue, pset_objects, n):
    print(f"built dbworker {n}")

def client_worker(clientQueue, psetObjects, dbQueue, clientResponse, p):
    print(f"built client worker {p}")

@app.on_event("startup")
def startup_event():
    start_lifespan_resources()

@app.on_event("shutdown")
def shutdown_event():
    stop_lifespan_resources()
```

The screenshot below shows the image building and launching then stopping a container. I terminated the process gracefully by running `docker stop` from another terminal. All of the processes are being launched in Docker.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the question of how many multiprocessing workers there will be?

Comment: Was aiming to establish a working example that replicated the setup. Code provided didn't run and had syntax errors.

Comment: There you go, now using multiprocessing as evidenced by the fact that the workers are starting out of sequence.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. Is the problem I'm having something to do with the async context manager then? I originally set things up like this with @app.on_event("startup") and got some deprecation warnings, hadn't ever used context manager before... Any thoughts on the advisability of this over other methods?

Comment: I don't believe you need it. Using `multiprocessing` should do the job already?

Comment: See the edits above - Really scratching my head...!

Comment: Could this be buffering of `print()` statements. What happens when you `docker stop` the process from another terminal?

Comment: Ahha, yes. Then I see the missing statements! What does this mean?!

Comment: The output of `print()` can be buffered, which means that it is effectively printed in batches. You can force it to print immediately with `print(flush=True)`. This means that your code has run but you have just not yet seen the `print()` statements. A couple of options: (1) flush the buffer using the `flush` argument or (2) use the `logging` package (which I _think_ is unbuffered and so should display immediately; I'm not sure how well it plays with `multiprocessing` though!). There are very likely other options too.

Comment: Actually I'm being a twit. Just add `ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` to the `Dockerfile` to make Python unbuffered.

Comment: Brilliant, yep this solved the problem thank you!! If you'd like to add the ENV PYTHONBUFFERED=1 line and the explanation to your answer I'll accept it.

Mad that there was actually "no problem"...